# __destruct and debug_backtrace() in PHP

Tags: php, destructor, debug-backtrace

I don't understand why

```
class test {
 
    
    function __destruct() {
        echo "I am the destructor<br>";
    }
    
    function __construct() {
         $this->a=debug_backtrace(); # <=== THIS LINE
    }
}
$myclass=new test();
unset($myclass);
echo "Last Line<br>";
```

out- and incommenting this line changes the order of the echo output. Why is the destructor not called by the unset() when the contsructor did a debug_backtrace() before?

Comment: PHP uses garbage collection for memory management and the [destructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) "will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object". Thus I reckon that PHP calls destructors as it sees fit and it isn't something you can control.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the backtrace returned by `debug_backtrace()` includes the function arguments including the implicit `$this` argument as `object`. Therefore, there's a cycle where the `test` instance referenced by `$myclass` also indirectly references itself, thereby keeping itself alive.

If you use `... = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)` that cycle is no longer present and the destructor is called right after the `unset($myclass)` call.

You can also call `gc_collect_cycles()` after `unset`, which will run the cycle collector and free the `test` instance, calling the destructor in the process.